# If a search algorithm is complete, does it need to be always optimal?

Tags: algorithm

If a Search algorithm is complete, does it need to be always optimal? What algorithms are complete but not optimal?

Comment: Can you include definitions of both terms, i.e. **optimal** and **complete**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To be complete, algorithm must find a solution if one exists; otherwise, it correctly reports that no solution is possible.

Example of complete, but not optimal algorithm would be linear search on a sorted array of integers. This algorithm will find a number if it present in the array, and correctly report if there is none, but you can run binary search which will beat linear search for arrays big enough.